# Correct statment but incorrect outcome

Tags: javascript, html, string, numbers, character

I was trying to make a simple sign in system(thats local). But, I keep getting the incorrect outcome and I'm quite confused. I'm 99% sure that my if statments are correct but it keeps alerting 'Not good'. I don't really have a idea why it does that because when I put 'abcd1' in the Username text field it still alerts 'Not good'.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>      
 <form id='form'>
    <title>Sign Up #1</title>
    <h3>Simple Signup system</h3>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="text1" id = "username">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input type="text" name="text2" id = "password">
    <div>
    
 <button type="button" id="subBtn">Sign Up!</button>
  </form>
    
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// /home/ceta123/Desktop/ab/Sedmi/index.html

var rUsername = document.getElementById('username').value;

var rPassword = document.getElementById('password').value;

// /main 

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('subBtn').addEventListener('click', onSubmit);
}

function onSubmit() {

    function onSubmit2() {
        if (rUsername.includes(Number))
            console.log('Good');
        else {
            alert('Not good!');
        }
    }
    
        if(rUsername == 'string' || rUsername instanceof String)
        {
            console.log('Is not a string')
        }
        else
        {
            onSubmit2();
        }
        
        document.forms['form'].submit();
    }
```

Comment: This feels like a homework. What do you expect to see this expression returns `"User5Name".includes(Number)`?

Comment: It's not lol, I'm just self learning javascript and doing small projects like this to improve.. Also, with the .includes number, I'm trying to check if the username var contains a number, which would be how I'm checking if the user set a good password.

Comment: Alright, try to put this into username `"function Number() { [native code] }"` (Without `"`), and you should not be seeing the alert `Not good!` anymore.

Comment: In computing, there is a phrase known as "Garbage-in, Garbage-out"  See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out

Answer (score 0):

1. This line doesn't make much sense in JS:

```
if (rUsername.includes(Number))
```

If you mean to check if username includes digits, you can use a regex instead:

```
if(\/d+\.test(rUsername))
```

2. To check if a variable is a string:

```
if(typeof rUsername === 'string')
```

instead of:

```
if(rUsername == 'string' || rUsername instanceof String)
```

3. You need to get the `username` value on submit, not when page is first loaded.
   So you need to include this line in your `onSubmit()` function:

```
var rUsername = document.getElementById('username').value;
```

Comment: You've gotta fix it all, that's not the only mistakes where his code's logic went wrong.

Comment: Could you explain how '\/d+\.test' works?

Comment: @StarterScripter here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

Use

if (typeof rUsername === 'string' || rUsername instanceof String)

Break your code into pieces by alert or console technique to have better outcomes.